# Scope property which depends on another scope property?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm just starting out with Angular and could use a hand re: binding to scopes.

I'm trying to load in data which populates a property.
I then want to update other properties based off this property, is there any way to trigger this easily?

At the moment I'm just doing:

1. Load JSON data
2. Set `mythings`
3. Trigger calculation of `mythings_processed`

I feel like I should be able to trigger **(3)** with **(2)**?

#### Example

Javascript

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.loadData = function () {
    $http.get('/api/orgs/gocardless/issues.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.mythings = data.things;
      $scope.generateCalculatedItems() // Surely this isn't necessary?
    });
  };

  $scope.generateCalculatedItems = function () {
    mythings_processed = {}; // Generated using mythings
    $scope.mythings_processed = mythings_processed;
  };
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="IssuesCtrl" ng-init="loadData()">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="thing in things">{{thing.id}}</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="processed_thing in mythings_processed">{{processed_thing.id}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm sure I'm doing something horrible to Angular here so I apologise!

I did feel like I should be able to do:

```
  $scope.mythingsProcessed = function () {
    mythings_processed = {}; // Generated using mythings
    return mythings_processed;
  };

   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="processed_thing in mythingsProcessed()">{{processed_thing.id}}</li>
   </ul>
```

But when I did, it gave me the error: `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: Example data/use case**

I have a list of items fetched via ajax:

```
{
  items: [
    {name: 'pete', value: 1},
    {name: 'john', value: 2},
    {name: 'pete', value: 3},
    {name: 'steve', value: 2},
    {name: 'john', value: 1}
  ]
}
```

I want to display all of these, but I also want to process (sum) them into:

```
{
  processed_items: [
    { name: 'pete', value: 4 }
    { name: 'john', value: 3 }
    { name: 'steve', value: 2 }
}
```

and then display these in a list as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to acheive. But to trigger (3) with (2) you could use the watch function of the $scope object:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.loadData = function () {
    $http.get('/api/orgs/gocardless/issues.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.mythings = data.things;
    });
  };

  scope.$watch('mythings', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.generateCalculatedItems();
  }

  $scope.generateCalculatedItems = function () {
    mythings_processed = {}; // Generated using mythings
    $scope.mythings_processed = mythings_processed;
  };
};
```

To bind mythings to mythings_processed you have to do the binding manually via the $watch-function in AngularJS.

Comment: This seems like what I need. I've just added an example above for the general problem I'm solving, if you could take a quick look and confirm this is still the best way that'd be ace.

Comment: Please see my new answer with a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

With your updated example I think the focus of your question shifted from the problem with the binding to how you could process the incoming data. Is that correct?

I made a plunker with a possible solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BMNmE5

I would process the data as soon as the success method is called. And not do a watch in this case.

```
$scope.loadData = function() {
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.mythings = data;
        $scope.mythingsProcessed = processThings(data);
    });
};
```

Then the function processThings makes the sum as you want them (it uses the underscore.js library):

```
var processThings = function(things) {
    var result = _.reduce(
        things,
        function(result, obj) {
            var storedObject = _.findWhere(result, {'name': obj.name});
            if(storedObject) {
                storedObject.value += obj.value;
                return result;
            }
            else {
                return _.union(result, _.clone(obj));
            }
        },
        []);
    return result;
};
```

Comment: This is actually what I ended up with in the end, although the process function you propose is interesting! However the actual answer to my question was your first one (triggering events by watching variables) so I've marked that as correct. Thanks for both!